# $R=\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ and let bars denote passage to $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$. Prove that $\bar{P}=(\bar{x},\bar{z} )$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> $R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ and let bars denote passage to $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$. Prove that $\bar{P} = (\bar{x},\bar{z} )$ is a prime ideal. Show that $\bar{xy} \in \bar{P}^{2}$, but no power of $\bar{y}$ lies in $\bar{P}^2$.

Let $P = (x,z)$ it's clear that $xy \in (x,z)$ and $z^2 \in (x,z)$ thus $ xy-z^2 \in (x,z)$ further $\overline{(xy-z^2)} \subseteq (\bar{x},\bar{y})$

so then $(\bar{x},\bar{z})/\overline{(xy-z^2)}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$.
Further, by Isomorphism Theorem 3

$\displaystyle \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)}{(\bar{x},\bar{z})/(xy-z^2)} \simeq \displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]}{(\bar{x},\bar{z})} \simeq \mathbb{Q}[y] $ which is an integral domain thus $\bar{P} = (\bar{x},\bar{z})$ is prime

Now, $\bar{P}^2 = (\bar{x}^2, \bar{xz}, \bar{z}^2)$ Also $\overline{xy-z^2} = \overline{0}$ so $\overline{xy} = \overline{z^2}$

so $\overline{xy} \in \overline{P}^2$

Finally, $\overline{P}^2 \subseteq \overline{P}$, suppose $\overline{y}^n \in \overline{P}^2$ then $\overline{y}^n \in \overline{P}$ then $y^n \in P$ so $0 = y^n \in \mathbb{Q}[y]$

but $\mathbb{Q}[y]$ is an integral domain and the only nilpotent element is $0$ hence no powers of $\overline{y}$ are in $\overline{P}^2$

Not sure this is correct

Comment: How are you getting from $\overline y^n\in\overline P$ to $y^n\in P$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant thats why I didn't think it was correct. I was trying to figure out if that was legal but I couldn't find anything anywhere that would help

Comment: But you're close.  Write $\overline y^n$ as a combination of the generators of $\overline P$, then write out the equation that implies in $\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ and then plug in $(0,1,0)$ to both sides and get a contradiction $1=0$.

Comment: do you mean in $\overline{P}^2$?  Im not quite following what you mean by plug in (0,1,0)

Comment: Sorry yes I meant $\overline P^2$.  Once you lift this to an equation in $\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ you'll have an equation of two polynomials in $x,y,z$, plug in the value $x=0$, $y=1$, $z=0$ and you'll get $0=1$ (I think).

Comment: The left hand side will be something like $y^n+k(xy-z^2)$ where $k\in\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$.  See how if you plug in $(0,1,0)$ you get 1?

Comment: hm, well I can see that if $\overline{y}^n \in \overline{P^2}$ then 

 $\overline{y}^n \in \overline{P}$ which means then $y^n+(xy-z^2) = 0 +(xy-z^2) = (xy-z^2)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$

Comment: So then write $\bar y^n=\bar f \bar x + \bar g \bar z$.  Then $y^n+a_1(xy-z)=(f+a_2(xy-z))(x+a_3(xy-z)) + (g+a_4(xy-z))(z+a_5(xy-z))$ for $a_i\in\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ $\forall$ $i=1,\dots,5$.  Or something like that.  Evaluate both sides at $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: Oops, that should be $xy-z^2$ in those terms, won't let me edit it now.

Comment: @GregoryGrant this is confusing me a bit. is there another way to see it?

Comment: Do you believe that $\overline y^n\in\overline P$ implies $\overline{y^n}=\overline {f(x,y,z)x + g(x,y,z)z}$ for some $f$ and $g$ in $\mathbb Q[x,y,z]$?