# Some possible typos in solution of 9.1.12 Dummit & Foote.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here is the question I was trying to solve:

Let $R = \mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ and let bars denote passage to $ \mathbb Q[x,y,z] / (xy - z^2).$ Prove that $\overline{P} = (\overline{x}, \overline{z})$ is a prime ideal. Show that $\overline{xy} \in \overline{P}^2$ but that no power of $\bar{y}$ lies in $\overline{P}^2.$

I was reading the following question solution here:

[$R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ and let bars denote passage to $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ Prove $\bar{P} = (\bar{x},\bar{z} )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264000/r-mathbbqx-y-z-and-let-bars-denote-passage-to-mathbbqx-y-z-xy-z)

The solution is mixing the $x$ and $y$ in some places. Like, in the following line:

"Let $P = (x,z)$ it's clear that $xy \in (x,z)$ and $z^2 \in (x,z)$ thus $ xy-z^2 \in (x,z)$ further $\overline{(xy-z^2)} \subseteq (\bar{x},\bar{y})$"

1- should not the last ideal be $(\bar{x},\bar{z})$ instead?

2- Also, did the authur intentially meant to say $xy \in (x,z)$? Is $xy \in (x,z)$ because the ideal is closed under multiplication by the elements of the ring?

Also, in the following line:

"$(\bar{x},\bar{z})/\overline{(xy-z^2)}$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$."

Why the ideal $(\bar{x},\bar{z})/\overline{(xy-z^2)}$ looks like this? should not it be called  $(\bar{x},\bar{z})$ only? what is the differnce between the bar over x and z and that over $(xy-z^2)$?

can someone explain these points for me please?

Comment: I always disliked the bar notation, and rarely used it myself. Never understood why some people don't want to use the usual coset notation, which would make it much more clear. Anyway, I believe you are right that there shouldn't be a bar over $(xy-z^2)$. The ideals of the quotient ring are given by the correspondence theorem, they have the form $J/(xy-z^2)$ there $J$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ that contains $(xy-z^2)$. As you can see, in the very next line the author removed the bar from his notation.

Comment: So the ideal in this line should be called $(\bar {x}, \bar{y})$ only .... am I correct? @Mark also what about the rest of my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⦁ Answering your *2nd* question, $xy∈(x,z)$ because $xy$ can be written as $xy=x\cdot{y}+z\cdot0$ and $x\cdot{y}+z\cdot0∈(x,z)$ since $y,0∈\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$. Thus, indeed $xy∈(x,z)$.

⦁ Answering your *1st* question, the bar notation here denotes the passage defined by the canonical ring homomorphism  $f∶\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]→\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ with $ker⁡f=(xy-z^2)$, so that $\overline{(xy-z^2)}=\overline{ker⁡f}=\overline{0}$, the zero ideal in the quotient ring $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)=\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}.$ And the zero ideal $\overline{0}=\overline{(xy-z^2)}$ is contained in *every* ideal of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$, namely, in $(\overline{x},\overline{y})$, $(\overline{x},\overline{z})$, ... . So, the initial author's statement "$\overline{(xy-z^2)}⊆(\overline{x},\overline{y})$" is obvious without almost any preceding argument and doesn't make much sense here.

⦁ Answering your *last* question, $(\overline{x},\overline{z})$ is already an *ideal* of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)=\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$, because $\overline{x},\overline{z}∈\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$. For the same reason as above, considering its quotient "$(\overline{x},\overline{z})/\overline{(xy-z^2)}$"  by the zero ideal $\overline{0}=\overline{(xy-z^2)}$ doesn't make  much sense, because this would mean the passage from our quotient ring $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)=\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$ to the quotient ring by $\overline{0}=\overline{(xy-z^2)}$ of this quotient ring: $\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}/\overline{(xy-z^2)}=\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}/\overline{0}≅\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$, so that we get the isomorphism of our quotient ring $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)=\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$ to itself; doesn't make much sense. 
So, yes, it *should be* "$(\overline{x},\overline{z})$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$".

⦁ The difference between the notations "$(\overline{x},\overline{z})$" and "$\overline{(xy-z^2)}$" is as follows: $(\overline{x},\overline{z})=(x+kerf,z+kerf)=(x+(xy-z^2),z+(xy-z^2))$

$\overline{(xy-z^2)}=(xy-z^2)/kerf=(xy-z^2)/(xy-z^2)=\overline{0}$,

if this is what you meant in your last question.

⦁⦁⦁ I think all of these possible "typos" arose, because the Third Isomorphism Theorem was applied not entirely correct in the original post. There should have been something like the following:
Since $xy-z^2=xy+z(-z)$, where  $y,-z∈\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$, so that $xy+z(-z)∈(x,z)$, it follows that $xy-z^2∈(x,z)$. Hence $(xy-z^2)⊂(x,z)$ (the containment is proper, since, for example, $z∉(xy-z^2)$). Now the Third Isomorphism Theorem for Rings can be applied:
$$\frac{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)}{(x,z)/(xy-z^2)} ≅ \frac{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}{(x,z)} ≅\Bbb{Q}[y]$$
Since $\Bbb{Q}$ is an integral domain, $\Bbb{Q}[y]$ is an integral domain, therefore, $(x,z)/(xy-z^2)$ is a *prime ideal* of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$. Denoting $P=(x,z)$ and using the bar notation as before, we get that $P/(xy-z^2)=(x,z)/(xy-z^2)$  ⇔  $\overline{P}=\overline{(x,z)}$ is a *prime ideal* of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)=\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$. Since the ring homomorphism $f$ (given above) is surjective, and $ker⁡f=(xy-z^2)$ is contained in $(x,z)$, it follows that $\overline{(x,z)}=(\overline{x},\overline{z})$ [it is not hard to prove using the mutual inclusion pattern]. Thus, $\overline{P}= (\overline{x},\overline{z})$ is a *prime ideal* of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)=\overline{\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]}$.

*P.S.* Hope this helps.