# What is the definition of coset for an $n^{th}$ power element $\bar{y}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Here is the question I am trying to understand the solution of the second part in it:

> Let $R = \mathbb Q[x,y,z]$ and let bars denote passage to $ \mathbb Q[x,y,z] / (xy - z^2).$ Prove that $\overline{P} = (\overline{x}, \overline{z})$ is a prime ideal. Show that $\overline{xy} \in \overline{P}^2$ but that no power of $\overline{y}$ lies in $\overline{P}^2.$ (This shows $\overline{P}$ is a prime ideal whose square is $\textit{not}$ a primary ideal.)

The solution of the second part is written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264000).

I just do not understand why in the comments the coset representing $\bar{y}^n$ has $a_1$ in it? Why this $a_1$ is not equal to 1 just like in the coset of $\bar{y}$ or why it is not equal to $n$?

Could someone help me in answering this question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "just like in the coset of $\bar{y}$". Let me try to fill out the proof sketched in the comments of the linked post.

By definition, $\bar{y}^n\in (\bar{x},\bar{z})$ means that
$$\bar{y^n}=\bar{y}^n = \bar{f} \cdot \bar{x}+\bar{g}\cdot \bar{z}, \quad \text{ for some }\quad  \bar{f},\bar{g}\in \Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2).$$
Now, we want to lift everything to $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$, and remembering the definition of the bar, we get
$$y^n+h_1 = (f+h_2)(x+h_3)+(g+h_4)(z+h_5)$$
for $h_i\in (xy-z^2)$. Note that these $h_i$ could be written $a_i(xy-z^2)$ for some $a_i\in \Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ as well. In particular, we may expand and collect all the terms in this ideal into one, $H\in (xy-z^2)$, and get
$$y^n = xf+zg+H.$$
Now you wonder, *is such a decomposition possible?* To which the answer is no: if this was true, it would be an identity of polynomials, in particular as functions on $\Bbb{Z}^3$, but the left hand side yields $1$, and the right $0$, when evaluated at $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: In this line "You could also name these $f,g$ to be $a_1,a_2$ as done in some of the comments" did you meant to say $\bar{f}, \bar{g}$ instead?

Comment: "Note that these $h_i$ could be written $a_i(xy-z^2)$ for some $a_i\in \Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ as well" why is this true ..... How do we know the exact $a_i$ for each term? say what is the value of $a_1$ corresponding to $h_1$?

Comment: So to be precise, the place I use $h_i$ is where the comments used $a_i$. I have removed the line you quote from my answer, since it only caused confusion.

To answer your second comment, this is the definition of lying in a principal ideal. In any (commutative) ring $R$ with $a\in R$, then $(a) := \lbrace ar \mid r\in R\rbrace$. So $h_i\in (xy-z^2)$ means $h_i=a_i\cdot (xy-z^2)$ for some $a_i\in R=\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$.  Also, I do *not* know what the $a_i$ look like, I just know they exist. Luckily, I do not need to know anything else.

Comment: what is the difference between $f$ & $x$? does not $H$ include x's?

Comment: $f$ could potentially be any element of $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$, but $x$ is a fixed element. It is like saying "what is the difference between $n$ and $2$" when $n$ is any integer. Yes, $2$ is also an integer, but a fixed one.

Comment: Does $H$ include $x's$? .................. I think everything other than the question I just stated is very clear now, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, $H$ is an element of the ideal $(xy-z^2)$, i.e. a polynomial. What does it mean for a polynomial to include $x$? It might have $x$ as a factor, or it might not. $x$ almost surely is a factor of one of its *monomials*. The defining property, though, is that $H$ is divisible by $(xy-z^2)$.